# Put mp3 files from raw folder into Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have mede an android app that can read music file from device
now i want to read music file from raw or asset folder insted
can you please help me i am an extra beginer
i have watched many youtube videos but it couldnt help

my mainactivity is

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

        if (checkPermission() == false){
            requesPermission();
            return;
        }

        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION
        };
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC +" != 0";
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,projection,selection,null,null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            AudioModel songdata = new AudioModel(cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(2));
            if (new File(songdata.getPath()).exists())
                songlist.add(songdata);
        }

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MusicListAdapter(songlist,getApplicationContext()));

    }
```

My list adapter is

```
public class MusicListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MusicListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<AudioModel> songlist;
    Context context;

    public MusicListAdapter(ArrayList<AudioModel> songlist, Context context) {
        this.songlist = songlist;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view,parent,false);
        return new MusicListAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        AudioModel songData = songlist.get(position);
        holder.track_name.setText(songData.getTitle());

        if (MyMediaPlayer.currentIndex==position){
            holder.track_name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        }else {
            holder.track_name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                MyMediaPlayer.getInstance().reset();
                MyMediaPlayer.currentIndex = position;
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,MusicPlayerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("LIST",songlist);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return songlist.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView track_icon;
        TextView track_name,track_artist;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            track_icon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.track_icon);
            track_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.track_name);
            track_artist = itemView.findViewById(R.id.track_artist);
        }
    }

}
```

my audio model is

```
public class AudioModel implements Serializable {
    String path;
    String title;
    String duration;
    String icon;

    public AudioModel(String path, String title, String duration) {
        this.path = path;
        this.title = title;
        //this.duration = duration;

    }



    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
}
```

if you can please help i will appriciate

Comment: What is the problem? List the files in assets and put them in your songlist. Then play them from assets.

Comment: Show your code where your media player plays a file from assets.

Comment: how can i  list the files in assets and put them in  songlist

Comment: Show your code where your media player plays a file from assets.

Comment: actualy media player play device files

Comment: Yes in your code. But can it play files from assets? As that is what you want. Start with one file from assets. Elaborate the problem.

Comment: And listing files in assets is pretty elementary. Just google a bit. Code is all over the internet.

Comment: this is my player activity  https://ctxt.io/2/AABQ_KFlFg  i want now to put mp3 files from asset or raw folder to the songlist instead of the song from the device

Comment: We already knew that. Your question was clear. Why do you repeat it? Better answer my questions and hints. Elaborate your problems.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding , forget about the mediaplayer for now all i want is to show raw files in the recycleview

Comment: Then you should be able to list the files in raw first. Are you? You are not elaborating your problem.

Comment: `forget about the mediaplayer for now` Well if it should be able to play files from assets or raw it should accept an inputstream for it. Now can it play from an input stream?