# Local mp4 in android device can't be played by uri before using registerForActivityResult to selected this local mp4

Tags: java, android

I want to develope the app that can play the local mp4 store in android device by click the button.

I know there can put the mp4 in raw file in project, then call mp4 from raw file, but I don't want using this method because the app size will become large, and I want let user can set which local mp4 they want to play by click mp4

I let user can select mp4 by those code below

```
String action[] = {"video/*"};
videoFilePickerLauncher.launch(action);
```

```
private final ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> videoFilePickerLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
new ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument(), new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(Uri result) {
        videoUri = result;
    }
})
```

I save the uri of selected mp4 by videoUri, and use it when I click button to play selected mp4, the code is like below

```
MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoUri );
exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
exoPlayer.prepare();
exoPlayer.play();
```

But the problem I met is that I can't play this mp4 again by uri directly after I close app, and open this app again

The mp4 needs to be selected first by registerForActivityResult everytime, but this behavior is inconvenient.

I have tried

```
context.grantUriPermission("com.XXX.XXX",uri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
```

But the permission will be denied, and show the exception like this:

`java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10790 does not have permission to content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A1000000431 [user 0]; you could obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs`

Are there any method can play local mp4 in android device by uri directly without selecting them first?

Or ares there any recommend can reach the same result?

Thank you!

Comment: `know there can put the mp4 in raw file in project, then call mp4 from raw file, ` Interesting! You should tell @Bra Him: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77119818/put-mp3-files-from-raw-folder-into-recyclerview?noredirect=1#comment135960017_77119818

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the method, I will share the solution below for everyone

The method is use

```
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION))
```

The full code likes this:

```
private final ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> videoFilePickerLauncher = registerForActivityResult( new ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument(), new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(Uri result) {
        videoUri = result;
        context.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(result,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    } })
```

Hope this can help other person who meets the same problem!
Thank you!